# В чем причина ошибки: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'execute'

Tags: python, postgresql, asyncio, asyncpg

создаю бд для тг-бот с помощью asyncpg.
Ниже представлен мой код

Это код из модуля, где я создаю соединение:

```
import asyncpg
from asyncpg.pool import Pool
from typing import Union
from config_data.config_db import ConfigDb, load_config_db

config: ConfigDb = load_config_db()


class DataBase:
    def __init__(self):
        self.pool: Union[Pool, None] = None

    async def create(self):
        pool = await asyncpg.create_pool(
            user=config.database.pg_user,
            password=config.database.pg_password,
            host='localhost',
            port='5432'
        )
        self.pool = pool
```

В модуле loader такой код:

```
from db.postgresql import DataBase

db = DataBase()
```

Вот код из модуля, где проводятся различные операции над бд:

```
from loader import db


async def add_name(name: str):
    await db.pool.execute('INSERT INTO users (name) VALUES ($1)', name)
```

Функцию add_name я использую в тот момент, когда пользователь вводит своё имя, но появляется ошибка: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'execute'

Помогите, пожалуйста

Comment: Инициализацию класса видим. Использование `create()` не видим.